# Numbered ordered list should be on same vertical line as select-Element

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I would like to have the selected list displayed at the same height as the select element.

[image]

If I remove the padding-left, then the select is too far left.

[image]

With padding-left it's too far to the right.

[image]

I also do not want to give an approximate pixel count for the padding-left to solve the problem. is there a more elegant solution?

```css
.flex {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items:center;
}

.flex > div {
  flex-basis:100%;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  background-color: #555;
  height: 50px;
}

.flex > div span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
} 

.flex > div > ol {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div>
    <span>Lorem Ipsum</span>
    <select name="" id="">
      <option value="loremIpsum">Lorem Ipsum</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <span>Lorem</span>
    <ol>
      <li>
        <select name="" id="">
      <option value="lorem">Lorem</option>
    </select>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should share your HTML and CSS code to make a snippet of your problem.

Comment: Maybe this will help you, list-style-position
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-position.asp

Comment: Post your HTML and CSS instead of showing pictures.

Comment: I will edit my question later. I do not have my code right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like that check the code out and you will see that i wrapped them in a parent div and give it display **flex** and defined a width for the **first** element then automatically the **second** element will start in the same line and for sure styling the **ol**

```
padding: 0;
list-style-position: inside;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/62q6zrnr/2

```css
   .one,
    .two {
      background-color: #ddd;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: flex-start;
      align-items: center;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      margin-bottom: 30px;
    }

    .base {
      width: 50%;
      flex-basis: 50%;
    }


    ol {
     padding: 0;
     list-style-position: inside;
   }
```

```html
  <div class="one">
  <p class="base">lorem</p>
  <select>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="two">
<p class="base">lorem 2</p>
    <ol>
      <li>
      <select>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
      </select>
      </li>
      <li>
        <select>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
      </select>
      </li>
      <li>
           <select>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
      </select>
      </li>
      <li>
        <select>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
      </select>
      </li>
      <li>
           <select>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
      </select>
      </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the `ol`?